# Best way to transfer files between .net web service and Mac web service

Tags: macos, web-services, hudson

DI have web service in .net that sends files...

What is the best simple way to write web service **on MAC**, that will accept those files,do stuff and send them back to server automatically?

I can't do it on .net so **what to choose**?